# What has been done here? (Root mean square integration)

Tags: integration

[image]

Taken from the wikipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_current#Root_mean_square_voltage) on RMS AC.

I dont understand the third step where we suddenly just have $\int_0^Tdt$. Could anyone explain the intermediary step?

(Any assistance with tagging would also be helpful)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The step is simply the linearity of the integration
$$\int_0^T [1-\cos(2\omega t + 2\phi)] dt = \int_0^T 1 \;dt 
- \int_0^T \cos(2\omega t + 2\phi) \;dt$$
The second integral on the RHS is zero, because you integrate over the complete period (remember $\omega T= 2 \pi).$